# How to setup slim for external links

Tags: slim

All my `<a>` tag are prepended by:

`http://localhost/site/externalLinkUrl/`

How do I solve this so I just get:

```
externalLinkUrl/
```

This is my index file:

```
require 'Server/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get(...);
$app->run();
```

Comment: Please provide some more information (sample code) on how the URL's are constructed by your Controller or in your View.

Comment: Any <a href="externalURL"> in my html is prepended by mySiteURL, which makes it impossible to link to external URLs, thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply prefix your external links with `http://` or `https://`.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">
```

It's not a Slim issue, it's normal behaviour when specifying a relative link. When you create relative links, the browser will prepend the path of the current file to the link:

```
<a href="example/">
```

Slim provides a way to generate proper local links via its `urlFor()` route helper:

```
// Create a named route
$app->get('/myroute/:myparam', function ($myparam) use ($app) {
    // ...
})->name('myroute');

// Generate a URL for the named route
$url = $app->urlFor('myroute', array('myparam' => 'foo'));
```